# Are questions about Sheepit on topic? We do have a tag for it, after all

Tags: discussion

We, myself included, just closed [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239758/sheepit-render-farm) about SheepIt because it's off topic, but I think that was a mistake.  Before I propose reopening, I want to discuss why I think it should be, to see what the sense of the community is.

The problem with Sheepit, is that we have a tag for it, and there are existing answered questions that weren't closed as out of bounds.  For that reason, I think it fits the rules about being on topic.

If it's off topic, then how should we deal with the existing questions?  If they're on topic, than shouldn't this one also be?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned I'm fine with questions about third party addons or services even commercial ones,  as long as they related to Blender and the question is about regular operation or learning how to employ them. If it is trouble shooting issues, broken functionality, bugs, service outages or any type of malfunction that is clearly unintentional, then I'm of the opinion that it is the job of the authors to give support. Especially if it is a commercial addon or subscription service the user is paying for, then support from the creators is to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm promoting the answer in the comments to what I believe should be the general rule about whether add-ons are on topic. [Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) commented from their personal viewpoint, but I think the answer is a good general answer.  I've paraphrased a bit to make it so.

Questions about third party addons or services even commercial ones, are on topic as long as

- they are related to Blender; and
- the question is about regular operation or learning how to employ them.

If the question involves

- trouble shooting issues,
- broken functionality,
- bugs in the addon,
- service outages, or
- any type of malfunction that is clearly unintentional,

it is the job of the authors to give support. (and thus off-topic here.) Especially if it is a commercial addon or subscription service the user is paying for, then support from the creators is to be expected.